# I can not change the value with .onAppear(), .onTapGesture() function and with a NavigationLink in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mobile

I am stuck with little problem ,
I can not change the value with .onAppear(), .onTapGesture() function and with a NavigationLink in SwiftUI

If anyone can tell me how to solve it ?
Regards,

VIEW ONE

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
        List{
        ForEach(0..<4){ numero in
           NavigationLink(
       
            destination: DetailView().onAppear(){
//This function is not working 
                vm.takeNumber(number: numero)
            },
            label: {
                Text(String(numero))
            })
 
        }
    }
    }
    }    
}
```

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var numero:Int = 0    
    func takeNumber(number: Int) {
        numero = number
    }
}
```

VIEW TWO

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
// My number is not updated 
        Text(String("My NUMBER : \(vm.numero)"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@StateObject` creates a fresh copy of your model.

Try changing it to

```
@ObservedObject var model: ViewModel
```

in `DetailView` and pass it as argument in `ContentView`.

Good read: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-the-difference-between-observedobject-state-and-environmentobject